# How to share aggregate types (for ex. custom structures) between several sources in the same package

Tags: go

Let's suppose my `server.go` receives aggregate data, feeds the corresponding structure instance and passes if to a function in `treatOne.go`
Where to declare and to include such common types?

Comment: You declare them wherever you want. (as long as it's a top level declaration)

Comment: Hard to say, because the unit of significance in Go is the *package*, not the *file*. If those files are in the same package, then it doesn't matter. If they're in different packages, you likely want a third package that both of the others can import.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following can be done :

1. If server.go and treatOne.go belong to the same package, you can use the custom struct directly.
2. If server.go and treatOne.go do not belong to the same package, you can have the custom struct defined publicly in any of the files (depends on semantics of the struct). You can define a public custom struct by having the first letter capitalized.
3. If server.go and treatOne.go do not belong to the same package, you can have a third package which serves the custom struct purpose and define the custom struct in that package and make it publicly defined. This is a better way to go about it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks nice, so in the same package, you just have to declare your custom type in any unique source you want, and you can use it in all sources, it's clearer for beginners :)

Comment: "called commons or utils" - try to avoid "junk drawer" packages like this. Packages should each have a distinct purpose, there should never be a "miscellaneous" package like this. Depending on what the struct is, it might belong in a "model" package, for example.

Comment: I beg to differ @Adrian. 
Where would you place say a configuration struct or a customized error struct implementing error interface or some string manipulation util functions ? 

You suggested having a third different package, how is that any different ?

Comment: It depends on the project, but configuration structs often go in a `config` package, and error structs generally either go in the package generating the error if it's a very specific error, or if it's used throughout the project, it can go in the model (since at that point it's part of the shared domain model). I suggested a third package, but it shouldn't be a "miscellaneous" package, it should be a package with a purpose (like all packages should be).

Comment: @Adrian : I agree to your philosophy and I can say I learnt something valuable today. Thank you. I will update my answer.

Comment: This is a common idea in every language, and is even called out explicitly in the Go blog: https://blog.golang.org/package-names#TOC_5. "Avoid meaningless package names. Packages named util, common, or misc provide clients with no sense of what the package contains."

Comment: I concede and I agree. Rather, I will get rid of any junk folders from my existing projects as well. Thank you.